# Как вывести значения массива при определенном значении i?

Tags: javascript, алгоритм

Имеется массив с двумя значениями. В цикле нужно выводить значения массива, если `i==3` или `i==5`. Но почему-то выводится только первое значение массива, а нужно выводить два значения.

```js
var arr = [
    'test1',
    'test2'
  ],
  result = $('#result'),
  str = '';
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
  if (i == 3 || i == 5) {
    str += arr[(i - 1) % 2] + ' ';
  }
}
result.html(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: потому что `(i-1) % 2` всегда ровно нулю в вашем случае, это остаток от деления , и у вас первый раз `2%2 = 0`  и `4%2 = 0`

Comment: @Razmik Galstyan, посмотрите вторую ссылку jsfiddle, теперь выводит только второе значение

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1tx4zzt8/1/), перенесённый из конца ответа.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для перевода `i=3 -> 0` и `i=5 -> 1` можно, например, воспользоваться формулой
`(i - 3) / 2`:

```js
var arr = [ "test1", "test2" ];
var $result = $("#result");
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    if (i == 3 || i == 5) {
        str += arr[(i - 3) / 2] + " ";
    }
}
$result.text(str);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

При произвольном количестве элементов и отсутствии вменяемой формулы для перевода `i` в индекс массива можно хранить данные в виде пар "ключ-значение":

```js
var map = {
    3: "test1",
    5: "test2",
    6: "test3"
};
var $result = $("#result");
var str = "";
for (var i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
    if (map[i] !== undefined) {
        str += map[i] + " ";
    }
}
$result.text(str);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ваш пример не работает если добавить третье значение в массив. Подскажите, как решить данную проблему, т.е. чтобы выводились все значения массива? Какую формулу нужно использовать?  https://jsfiddle.net/1tx4zzt8/3/

Comment: можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы корректно выводились все значения массива, не зависимо от количества значений массива?

Comment: @word конечно, не работает. Ведь в вопросе речь шла о массиве из двух элементов и `i=3 -> 0` и `i=5 -> 1`, и ни о чем другом. А тут внезапно выясняется, что элементов может быть больше. Добавил в конец ответа вариант с произвольным количеством элементов, без формул.